# Query org agenda build time?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, time-date

**Q**: how can I get the last time I built the `org` agenda buffer?

I've set an idle timer to rebuild my `org` agenda buffer every *x* minutes.  It works fine, but it's inefficient to rebuild if the agenda files have not been modified since the last rebuild.

I can get the last modification time of, say, the first agenda file with `(nth 5 (file-attributes (car org-agenda-files)))` and compare it to some hypothetical `last-agenda-rebuild` variable with `time-less-p`.  However, I don't know where to look for the last rebuild time (or if it's even stored anywhere).

Answer (score 1):

Idle timer uses `current-idle-time`  to run. So, you can't  get last time when it was activate. But you can save the time when it was active.

```
(defun org-build-agenda ()
  (set last-build-time (current-time-string)
   ;; build agenda)

(setq org-build-timer
      (run-with-idle-timer 5 t 'org-build-agenda))
```